# Repository Error: Repository Base does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am dealing with an issue that I have no idea how to work around. I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate and have been following this guide and its source to the T: [Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791740/Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram)

I have a problem building my first repository. It's giving me the following error: Error    1

> 'Test.EntityFramework.Repositories.TestRepositoryBase'
>   does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

This is the Repository:

```
public class UserInfoRepository : TestRepositoryBase<UserInfo, Guid>, IUserInfoRepository
{
}
```

While the base:

```
 public abstract class TestRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfRepositoryBase<TestDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    protected TestRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {

    }

    //add common methods for all repositories
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `public UserInfoRepository (IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider){}`

Comment: Hi Hamlet! Seems to have fixed the issue. Can you post as answer so I can mark it? thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base classes always force their signature of constructors to the derived classes. As you know the base class constructor should be called on derived class instance creation. If you define default(parameterless) constructor and try to `new` it there is only one constructor in base class which takes 1 argument and it should be called, but there is no argument to pass in. The base class non-default constructor should be called explicitly on derived class constructor implementation to provide ability to pass argument in. To fix the situation you should explicitly call base class constructor and pass argument in.

```
public UserInfoRepository (IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider)
      : base(dbContextProvider)
{}
```